# I'm looking for the asymptotic behavior of an integral involving a modified Bessel function of the second kind

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics, bessel-functions

Let $\beta>0$ and $\alpha$ real number fixed, $z$ is a positive parameter.

I'm looking for the asymptotic behavior (at least the leading term) as $z \to 0$ of the following integral:

$$
\int_0^{+\infty} \exp(-\alpha x) \,K_2\big(\beta\sqrt{x^2+z^2}\big)\,dx
$$

where $K_2$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Comment: Try integral representation of the Bessel function

Comment: Heuristic analysis shows that the main asymptotics term at $z\to 0$ is
$$I(z)=\int_0^\infty \exp(-\alpha x) \,K_2\big(\beta\sqrt{x^2+z^2}\big)\,dx\sim \frac{Const}{\beta^2 z}$$
Indeed, if we lead $z\to0$ and use [10.31.1][1]

$$I\sim\int_0^\infty \frac{2\exp(-\alpha x)}{\beta^2(x^2+z^2)} \,dx\sim\frac{2}{\beta^2}\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2+z^2}\sim\frac{\pi}{\beta^2z}$$
because at $z\to0$ the integral diverges near $x=0$.
More accurate evaluation (using, for instance, [10.32.8][2]) gives the same result.


  [1]: https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.31
  [2]: https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32